# Passed php variable from one file to another not in scope of if statement

Tags: php

How do I use a php variable which is transferred from one file (`search.inc.php`) into another (`anotherpage.php`) in if statement?

My connection with MySQL is correct but I can't use variable `$bilkon` (which is picked up from MySQL) in if statement in `anotherpage.php`.

When echo `$bilkon`  in `anotherpage.php`, I see the "Yes" response, but when I use this `$bilkon` in if statement I don't get the correct response. I got the "Bad" response from the if statement although I got on echo answer "Yes".

search.inc.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php'; 

if(isset($_GET['search_text'])){
    $search_text = $_GET['search_text'];

    if(!empty($search_text)){

        $query="SELECT * FROM kon WHERE sifkon LIKE '%$search_text%'";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        while($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

            echo $sifkon='<a href="anotherpage.php?search_text='.$query_row['sifkon'].'">'.$query_row['sifkon'].'  '.'</a>';
            echo $nazkon = $query_row['nazkon'].'<br>';
            $bilkon = $query_row['bilkon'].'<br>';
            $strknj = $query_row['strknj'].'<br>';
            $devknj = $query_row['devknj'].'<br>';
            $orjkon = $query_row['orjkon'].'<br>';
            $tiporj = $query_row['tiporj'].'<br>';
            $_SESSION['test']=$bilkon;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

anotherpage.php

```
<?php
include 'search.inc.php';

echo  $_SESSION['test'];//Yes
if ($_SESSION['test'] == 'Yes'){
    echo 'Good';
}else {
    echo 'Bad';
}
?>
```

Comment: You asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45722728/4265352) one hour ago and it was closed as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: @axiac I know and they went and deface the original post from it, without marking it as edits. I had to roll it back to its original state.

Comment: Regarding the title, there is no such thing as "scope of if statement". Have you read the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$bilkon` has a `<br>` at the end, you add it, but you dont check for that

```
if ($_SESSION['test'] == 'Yes<br>'){
```

better option to remove the `<br>` until you need it.

for future debugging use

```
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
```

instead of `echo`, it catches things like html, white space, etc.